# Sorting strings in array without sorting function - Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm trying to create a sorting algorithm without the sorting function in Ruby. I've based it of the idea of insertion sort. The idea is that the function checks whether the nth value of each two words are same, and if so n increases by one until one value is larger than the other. In that case the words might get switched. However, my function keeps freezing. Any ideas why?

```
words = ["my","favorite","animal", "are", "the", "elephant", "and", "the", "antelope", "and", "the", "favela"]

#Convert all letters into numbers. Output individual words as arrays.
converted_words = words.map(&:chars).map { |letters| letters.map { |letter| letter.to_i 36 } }
puts converted_words.to_s

i = 1
x = 0
while i < converted_words.length
  if converted_words[i][x] == converted_words[i-1][x]
    x = x + 1
  else
    if converted_words[i][x] < converted_words[i-1][x]
      converted_words[i], converted_words[i-1] = converted_words[i-1], converted_words[i]
      i = 0
      x = 0
    else
      i = i + 1
    end
  end
end
puts converted_words.to_s
```

Comment: Can you please sample output?

Comment: I wish. The terminal literally does not provide an output. I have to abort every time.

Comment: Desired output is this, right? => ["and", "and", "animal", "antelope", "are", "elephant", "favela", "favorite", "my", "the", "the", "the"]

Comment: Yes, it is exactly that.

Comment: If you don't increment `i`, the function loops forever.

Comment: Seems like this has been previously answered : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068242/alphabetical-sorting-of-an-array-without-using-the-sort-method

Comment: @YvesDaoust, but I do increment i. I think it's x I'm having trouble with.

Comment: @zee, yes, you are right, a simliar question has been asked before. I, however, am trying to compare each letter in each word, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Benisburgers: are you so sure ?

Comment: As @YvesDaoust pointed out, there are conditions in which you don't increment `i`. And, yes, you have problems with `x`. Whenever you change `i`, you must reset `x`. Also, if you set `i=0` and then try to access `converted_words[i-1][0]`, you're going off back end of the array. And you don't have a termination condition to stop at the end of a word. You need to fire up your debugger and single-step through your code to see where it's going off the rails.

Comment: Also, what you have here is a horribly inefficient sorting algorithm that bears little resemblance to insertion sort. If I'm reading intention correctly, you search forward until you find an item that's out of place. You swap items, and then start over from the beginning. So if you wanted to move an item from the end of the array to the beginning, it would take `n` passes over the array. That makes for an O(n^3) algorithm. Given a sufficiently large array, it wouldn't actually go into an infinite loop; it would just seem like an infinite loop.

Comment: @JimMischel, any suggestions for a debugger I could use?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ruby development environments. I thought they all had debuggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have solved the issue. Thank you for all your help.

I reordered my algorithm: First checking `if converted_words[i][x] < converted_words[i-1][x]`, and **then** checking `if converted_words[i][x] == converted_words[i-1][x]`.

I also need to check whether `if converted_words[i][x] != nil && converted_words[i-1][x] != nil`, in order to avoid a NoMethodError (thanks Cary Swoveland). 
Finally I combined the two algorithms.

I also realized that I did not need to convert the letters to numbers, as ruby *knows* which letters are larger. So instead, I left the characters as letters.

I'm aware that the code is not very efficent. If you have any suggestions on how to improve or simplify the algorithm, I would be happy to hear them.

Here's the code:

```
words = ["my","favorite","animals", "are", "the", "elephant", "and", "the", "antelope", "and", "the", "favela"]
puts words.to_s
#Convert all letters into numbers. Output individual words as arrays.
ordered_words = words.map(&:chars).map { |letters| letters.map { |letter| letter } }

i = 1
x = 0
while i < ordered_words.length
  if ordered_words[i][x] != nil && ordered_words[i-1][x] != nil
    if ordered_words[i][x] < ordered_words[i-1][x]
      ordered_words[i], ordered_words[i-1] = ordered_words[i-1], ordered_words[i]
      i = 1
      x = 0
    else
      if ordered_words[i][x] == ordered_words[i-1][x]
        x = x + 1
      else
        i = i + 1
        x = 0
      end
    end
  else
    if ordered_words[i][x] == nil && ordered_words[i-1][x] == nil
      i = i + 1
      x = 0
    else
      if ordered_words[i][x] == nil
        ordered_words[i], ordered_words[i-1] = ordered_words[i-1], ordered_words[i]
        i = 1
        x = 0
      else
        i = i + 1
        x = 0
      end
    end
  end
end

joined_words = []
ordered_words.each do |word|
  joined_words.push(word.join)
end
puts joined_words.to_s
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not "freeze"; running it raises this exception:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method '<' for nil:NilClass)
```

in the line:

```
if converted_words[i][x] < converted_words[i-1][x]
```

We immediately see the problem, though the cause is not yet known. The receiver of the method `<` is `converted_words[i][x]`. As the error message says that `nil` does not have a method `<`, we infer that `converted_words[i][x]` is `nil`.<sup>1</sup> That means that an index is out-of-range (examples of an index being out-of-range are `[1,2][412] #=> nil` and `[1,2][-3] #=> nil`). If `i` were out-of-range the expression would reduce to `nil[x] < ...`, which would raise an exception that `nil` does not have a method `NilClass#\[\]]`. That's not our exception message so we conclude that `x` must be out-of-range.

To see why this is happening, suppose:

```
words = ["a", "ab"]
```

Then

```
converted_words =
  words.map(&:chars).map { |letters| letters.map { |letter| letter.to_i 36 } }
  #=> [[10], [10, 11]] 
i = 1
x = 0
while i < converted_words.length
  #=> while 1 < 2 => while true, so enter the loop
if converted_words[i][x] == converted_words[i-1][x]
  #=> if converted_words[1][0] == converted_words[0][0] => if 10 == 10 => true
```

so execute

```
x = x + 1
  #=> x = 0 + 1 => 1
```

and attempt to repeat the loop.

```
while i < converted_words.length
  #=> while 1 < 2 => while true, so repeat the loop
if converted_words[i][x] == converted_words[i-1][x]
  #=> if converted_words[1][1] == converted_words[0][1] => if 11 == nil => false
```

so execute (`else`).

```
if converted_words[i][x] < converted_words[i-1][x]
  #=> converted_words[0][1] < converted_words[-1][1] => if nil < 11
  #=> NoMethodError (undefined method '<' for nil:NilClass)
```

Error messages contain valuable information. Study them carefully!

<sup>1 The error message "`nil` has no method `<`" is here equivalent to, "[NilClass](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/NilClass.html) has no instance method `<`".</sup>

Comment: Thank you so so much. That is what I was looking for. Thank you for all the hard work. But how were you able to access the error message? My terminal simply stops and does nothing.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into IRB and ran it. (Ruby v2.5.1, but I don’t think it’s a version issue.)